# Load and append external html file with jQuery and JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I use the following code:

```
<div id="success"></div>
<script>$.getJSON('http://daytona.bg/test.html', function(data) { $(data.html).appendTo("#success"); } );</script>
```

The script is loading and appending but only if the test.html is on my computer.
If it's on a external domain - it's not working.

How can it be done?

Comment: See this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use JSONP, the cross-domain version of JSON to get data from external domain.

Here is a link with a lot of useful information: [jQuery AJAX cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain)